# No Internet or Bluetooth on fresh install 20.04

Tags: system-installation, bluetooth, internet

I did a dual boot on my new Asus G14 and followed the Ubuntu dual boot option. I noticed it was weird it didn't ask me to sign into my network. Now that I am in Ubuntu I noticed that there is no option for Network and Bluetooth as well. I don't have any wired connections either since I installed from usb, But I have connection on the windows side.

edit: I also tried Pop!_OS in demo mode and it has the exact same issue.  The Wifi card in the laptop is MediaTek Wi-Fi 6 MT7921 Wireless LAN Card, 802.11ax.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

https://imgur.com/gallery/nQFIO5H?fbclid=IwAR10kKr3nFfMWyyjkVheyUvZQZBGXMPEv6z1fQAlYbi1mJPKH6jQ2Vk1ZgE

Comment: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/mediatek -> MT7921 needs kernel 5.12 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I just bought Acer Aspire 5 A515-56-555H which built-in with Media Tek MT7921 Wifi, but no driver available for Ubuntu.

I use alternative way that I bought a USB dongle "Comfast CF-727B" with Wifi 1300Mbps and Bluetooth 4.2 (2 in 1).

Ubuntu 20.04 able to auto-detect Bluetooth but no default driver for Wifi (RTL8822BU).

I am able to download, compile and install driver (RTL 88x2bu).

You may refer to this article:

https://dev.to/limal/install-rtl88x2ub-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-10-1ofp

If modprob fail with permission error, you may disable UEFI secure boot (https://vovaprivalov.medium.com/fixing-problem-with-missing-wifi-adapter-on-ubuntu-18-04-dec50879a47e):

Install mokutil:

```
sudo apt-get install mokutil
```

Check SecureBoot status:

```
mokutil --sb-state
```

If status is "enabled" , you may disable with following command:

```
sudo mokutil --disable-validation
```

Now enter a temporary password between 8 to 16 digits. We will use this password later. Enter the same password again to confirm.

Once it’s done reboot the system and press any key when you see the blue screen (MOK management). Select Change Secure Boot state.

Enter the password you had selected before and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Select Yes to disable Secure Boot in shim-signed. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to finish the whole procedure. That’s all.

Answer (score 0):

I have laptop Lenovo Legion 5 with Wi-Fi card MT7921 (802.11ax). In Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I was not able to activate Wi-Fi interface. There is no adequate driver for kernel version 5.11 in repositories

I solved situation by upgrade to Ubuntu 21.10 which has kernel 5.13. I can  connect to both the 2.4 and the 5 GHz bands now including 802.11ax standard.

The same kernel version 5.13 should be in 20.04.4 LTS released in 2022. **Try to upgrade your system**.